# Show that scalar field f must be equal at two points...

Tags: calculus

If $\nabla f$ is proportional to $x\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k}$.

The two points are $(0,0,a)$ and $(0,0,-a)$

So far what I have is that along the z-axis from the origin the function doesn't change with respect to the x and y directions, so it only changes with respect to z. But I am unsure as to how to show that the scalar field must be equal at these points.

Solving f along the z axis, we have $f = ce^{kz} + D$. How can f at the two point be shown to be equal?

Comment: The restrictions of your problem are not clear. Given any function of the form $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, it follows immediately that $\nabla f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$. We know nothing about $\nabla f$ except that it is somehow supposed to imply that $f(0,0,a)=f(0,0,-a)$. Your conclusion that the function doesn't change with respect to $x$ and $y$ along the $z$-axis moreover is illogical; certainly, if this were the case, then $f(0,0,a)=f(0,0,-a)$, but this does not imply the converse. By your logic, I could just as easily say $f$ is even with respect to $z$.

Answer (score 2):

From $\nabla f \propto x\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k}$ we have the constraint $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \propto z$

This has solutions of the form $f(0,0,z)=B(\frac{z^{2}}{2}+C)$, which has even parity as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the equation:

$\nabla f = <\frac {\partial f}{\partial x},\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} , \frac {\partial f}{\partial z}>$

Say K be the proportionality constant.

Hence $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x} = Kx \Rightarrow f = \frac {x^2}{2}+C(y,z)$.

Coming to $\frac {\partial f}{\partial y} = Ky \Rightarrow \frac {\partial C}{\partial y} = Ky \Rightarrow C=\frac {y^2}{2} + D(z)$

Going this way, you can get $f = K\frac {x^2+y^2+z^2}{2} + M$. 
$M$ is integration constant (a number).

Now clearly the value of $f$ is constant the given points specified.

Answer (score 0):

If we know that
$$
\nabla f \approx x\hat{i} + y \hat{j} + z \hat{k} \implies \nabla f = kx \hat{i} + ky \hat{j} + kz \hat{k}
$$
for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$. From this we can deduce that
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = kx \implies f = \frac{k}{2}x^2 + g(y,z) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = ky \implies g = \frac{k}{2}y^2 + h(z) \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial z} = kz \implies h = \frac{k}{2}z^2 + C
$$
with $C \in \mathbb{R}$. So in the end we get that:
$$
f(x,y,z) = \frac{k}{2}\left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2\right) + C
$$
and finally thus:
$$
f(0,0,a) = \frac{k}{2}a^2 + C, f(0,0,-a) = \frac{k}{2}a^2 + C
$$
are equal!